# Catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExc

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int col=6;
        int row=7;
        String[][] tablero=new String[col][row];
        rellenarTablero(tablero);

        int grid = row*col;
        for(int count=0;count<=grid;count++){
            if(count%2==0){
                jugador1(tablero,in);
            }
            else{
                jugador2(tablero,in);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void jugador1(String[][] tablero,Scanner in){
        int row=7;
        int col1=preguntarHastaAcertar(in,"Jugador1!Que columna?");
        for(row=row-1;row>=0;row--){
            if(tablero[col1][row]=="."){
                tablero[col1][row]="X";
                break;
            }
        }
        imprimirTablero(tablero);
    }
    public static void jugador2(String[][] tablero,Scanner in){
        int row=7;
        int col2=preguntarHastaAcertar(in,"Jugador2!Que columna?");
        for(row=row-1;row>=0;row--){
            if(tablero[col2][row]=="."){
                tablero[col2][row]="O";
                break;
            }
        }
        imprimirTablero(tablero);
    }
    public static void rellenarTablero (String[][] tablero){
        int col;
        int row;
        for(row=0;row<7;row++){
            for(col=0;col<6;col++){
                tablero[col][row]=".";
            }
        }
    }
    public static void imprimirTablero (String[][] tablero){
        int col;
        int row;
        for(row=0;row<7;row++){
            for(col=0;col<6;col++){
                System.out.print(tablero[col][row]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    public static int preguntarHastaAcertar (Scanner in,String mensaje){
        while(true){
            System.out.print( mensaje );
            String linea =in.nextLine();
            try{
                return (Integer.parseInt(linea)-1);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.print(linea+" no es un numero!");
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                System.out.println(linea+" no es un columna correcta!");
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I put a catch for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e in this along with the numberFormatExcp e ?I want it too show a mesege that the column selected is not correct and keep asking me until getting the column that will actualy work.Im kinda learnind :D

Comment: Why do you want to catch it?  Why not just check the index against the length before reading from the table?

Comment: you will not get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds for a parseInt, however you will get it if your array index variables are not correct for your tablero[][].  You need to show more code to solve the problem.

Comment: word by Joshua Bloch : `Exceptions are, as their name implies, to be used only for excpetion conditions; they should never be used for ordinary control flow`. It's bolded out in his second book. If you continue this type of stupidity, next time , he will bold and UPPERCASE them.

Comment: please post the code of how your table is created, the call to use the loop and what you are trying to do with the for loop for the 2d array.

Comment: .... you are still not saying what it is your trying to do with any part of your code, you are getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds ex from your array loop, please post entire code for what you are trying to do.

Comment: you should be checking the input against the col/row of your array.  if it is greater than the col/row you need to print the error not within the range. do not allow it to go to the array loop. that is where your errors are coming from, you are allowing numbers greater than the col/row width/height to be used in your loops

Comment: See my edited answer to handle this directly in `preguntarHastaAcertar`. I decided to make it recursive instead of iterative but the principle is the same

Comment: ooooh the if goes INTO the try thing.That solved it. Thanks man ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` should generally not be handled as it is considered as a programming error. However, if you want to do this.. just write it the more natural way :

```
try {
    for(row=row-1;row>=0;row--) {
       if(tablero[col1][row]==".") {
           tablero[col1][row]="X";
           break;
       }
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // do something
}
```

However, from your edited message, it would be better to do something like this :

```
public static int preguntarHastaAcertar (Scanner in, String mensaje, int nrows){
     System.out.print(mensaje);
     String linea = in.nextLine();
     try {
         int value = Integer.parseInt(linea) - 1;
         if (value >= 0 && value < nrows)
             return value; 
         else {
             System.out.print(linea + " no es una columna correcta!");
             return preguntarHastaAcertar(in,mensaje,nrows);
         }
     } catch (NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.print(linea + " no es un numero!");
         return preguntarHastaAcertar(in,mensaje,nrows);
     }            
}
```

Comment: ... guys look above the parseint, he has an array with index variables, but does not show the code how they are set or the size of the 2d array he is using.  you will not get a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds ex from a parseint.

Comment: Hmm that's right, so the question is even more pointless as it seemed (only a syntax question)

Answer (score -2):

Just tag on another catch statement..

```
    try{
        return (Integer.parseInt(linea)-1);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.print(linea+" is not a number!");
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error){}
```

Comment: not necessariliy WhatEverException. Won't work for the exception in lower hierarchy of exception tree.

Comment: Very true, this was simply to say that you could do this for this kind of scenario

Comment: ... you will not get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception from a parseint.

Comment: it returns the integer and still shows the array out of bounds

Comment: Georgi, your parseint is not the problem here

Comment: @DavidColer The question states how do i add an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException along with the NumberFormatException. I get a minus one for answering exactly what is asked?

Comment: I cant minus you, I don't have the rep.

Comment: You statement answers his question. I was stating that it was just not right for all scenario. but that negative vote was not me either.